# Did I set up my port forwarding wrong?

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a D-Link DIR-655 (with v2 firmware). I set up my virtual server like this:

[image]

Port forwarding doesn't work for me, however virtual server did at once point. Can you see me says port 200 isnt open. What'd I do wrong?

Comment: What kind of service are you trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try those same settings on the Port Forwarding page instead of the Virtual Server page.

Comment: I have and it didn't work. I had the same problem a long while back and only virtual server worked. Now neither of them work. I just tried it again and it didn't work.

Comment: I have that same router set up with port forwarding and it works fine. The only difference is that on my router, the Traffic Type corresponding to 'Both' is 257 instead of 256. Try setting it to 'TCP' and see what happens. Also, what operating system are you using when you run the Can You See Me test? It's possible that the O/S is doing the blocking.